# Can't launch Gparted from applications menu but CAN launch from terminal

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, disk-management, disk-utility

I'm a newbie on this OS. I was able to install Gparted on my 20.04 version of Ubuntu. When attempting to launch Gparted from the applications menu, I see that program's name spin on the top left corner, and ultimately doesn't open.

However, launching that program from the command line using sudo gparted works just fine.

What's wrong with the application menu version of Gparted?

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated then try again.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. You can reinstall the application on your Ubuntu 20.04, It might fix your problem.
I installed Gparted using itslinuxfoss.com guide and it is working totally fine.